# JPA top one row that match criteria

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using JPA and need help with the same.
Current query looks as below

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM orders o " +
    "WHERE (o.type = 'type1'... " +
    "       ) " +
    "   OR (o.type = 'type2' ...... " +
    "       ) "      
)
Page<Order> getOrders(Pageable pageable);
```

to the above now I have to add another "OR" condition (type3 as below) for which I need to get only 1 record that match criteria i.e limit one only for this new OR condition.

Need to limit 1 for below criteria only

```
    "   OR (o.type = 'type3' ...... " +
    "       limit 1) "
```

how can I do that in JPA?

Comment: JPA isn't a good fit for this.  You're thinking in terms of SQL.  JPL is an attempt to hide SQL and allow the developer to think in terms of objects.  If you are still thinking SQL, I'd recommend using Spring Boot JDBC Template.  It'll let you execute raw SQL and map the result into an object as you see fit.  JPA need not be your complete solution for relational databases.

Comment: ok. Thank you, for the response.

Comment: I think there is no problem with JPA nor Spring data to have this done. But first you should add your Orders entity (or is this native query?) to the question. Also when you limit queries you might be interested about what is on the top/bottom (not necessarilly). You should describe your problem a bit more detailed to have a good answer.

Comment: You can use a native query by separating your query then `UNION` both result `@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM orders o .... UNION SELECT o FROM orders o ......", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: Thank you for responses